# Webapp that shows trends in short timeframe (finer than Google Trends's 1-month units)

Tags: gratis, web-apps

I want to see recent trends, but Google Trends' graph only has 1 number per month, which is not enough to see this week's trends:

[image: Bee challenge]

Is there a similar webapp, but finer-grained?

- Trend measure for at least each week, ideally every day
- Can compare several terms
- Free
- Bonus if I can filter to see trends in different categories like news, social networks, memes, and by area.

Comment: The **CSV Export** of Google Trends offers weekly results if I remember correct. More [here](https://support.google.com/trends/answer/4365538?hl=en). But not daily :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Trends actually can do that, there is a difficult-to-miss drop-down menu to change the scale:

[image]